# add image url in CSV in magento

Tags: image, magento, url, csv

I need to  customize product CSV and want to use images' urls to upload  images in Magento. Can anyone advise me with how to do this?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks MUK, How to use Magmi. I have downloaded the magmi and also extract the folder in the magento directory.

Comment: type in browser yoursite.com/magmi/web/magmi.php .Here configure your mysql username and password. For import format see the wiki of magmi

Answer (score 2):

I know you can't use URLs using the normal CSV import method(s). Use [magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) instead. It's worth the while learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `image url in image column` and `upload all images to media->import` folder

Comment: This is an answer to the question. Please read the question and my answer carefully.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need to import the images from other website link. I have only images URL. Can you please now guide me in this situation. Also there is no import folder in media folder. Should i need to create a new folder in media with name of import and upload all images?

Comment: exactly..create a folder named import ...and put all the images there and just add the image name..on your CSV.....suppose on import folder there is an image name magento.jpg. Then just add magento.jpg in you CSV

Comment: But as I write in previous comments, That I have images on the other website(On other Server www.photobucket.com). I need to import images by using images links like this (http://i880.photobucket.com/albums/ac7/Creationsmotorsport/Surrounds/IMG_1589.jpg). then how can I do this.

Comment: First of all if you want to show images from other site then your page speed will be low. SO you need to find a way to download those images and put those in media directory. I never did like that..so do some google search..it always returns positive ans